react-native-element-dropdown container issues
I have width of my parent view 50% and i have placed my drop down at flex start but when i press the dropdow to open the container it doest not open the container under the dropdown it opens it in the center of the screen horizontally, and show only 2 values for more i have to scroll.i should show 4
What Should i do?
This is the image to describe problem
<View
style={{
width: '50%',
borderColor: 'rgb(0, 145, 234)',
paddingLeft: 10,
paddingRight:10
}}>
                      <Dropdown
                        style={{
                          padding: 7,
                          borderColor: 'rgb(0, 145, 234)',
                          borderWidth: 2,
                          marginTop:5, 
                        //   position: 'relative',
                        }}
                    containerStyle={{ position: 'relative',left: 0,
                   }}
                        maxHeight={data.length * 50}
                        itemTextStyle={{ color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', }}
                        data={data}  
                        labelField="label"
                        valueField="value"
                        label="Dropdown"
                        // placeholder={'Scan Type'}
                        placeholder={selectedDropdown}
                        value={selectedDropdown}
                        onChange={(item) => { onChangeScanType(item.value)}}
                      />
                    </View> 


Can you try the below code it will work
<View style={{ width: '100%', borderColor: 'rgb(0, 145, 234)', paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
  <Dropdown
    style={{
    padding: 7,
    borderColor: 'rgb(0, 145, 234)',
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginTop: 5,
   }}
   containerStyle={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%' }} // Adjusted to fill the parent view
   maxHeight={data.length * 50}
   itemTextStyle={{ color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' }}
   data={data}
   labelField="label"
   valueField="value"
   label="Dropdown"
   placeholder={selectedDropdown}
   value={selectedDropdown}
   onChange={(item) => { onChangeScanType(item.value) }
   itemHeight={50} // Increase item height if necessary
  />
</View>


No it is not working

What error you are facing now @junaidanwar

There is no error here it is showing the container in center
